# How to scale a image based on its rotation

Tags: c#, image, xna, rotation, scale

I want to scale an image so that the image is always the size of the screen no matter how it is rotated. Does anyone have any ideas on going about this? By the way I am programing this in C# with xna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something similiar to this, although I'm unsure how you expect to draw the texture. It would be easiest by using triangles and texture wrapping them.

This is how I got the new width and new height after rotating:

```
Matrix origin = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
Matrix scale = Matrix.CreateScale(1f);
Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(rotate));
Matrix translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);

Vector2 pos1 = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(Texture.Width / 2, Texture.Height / 2), origin * scale * rotation * origin);
Vector2 pos2 = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(Texture.Width, Texture.Height), origin * scale * rotation * translation);

int width = (int)Math.Abs(pos2.X - pos1.X) * 2;
int height = (int)Math.Abs(pos2.Y - pos1.Y) * 2;

float scaleX = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / width);
float scaleY = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / height);
```

You will probably figure out the best way to draw this, because an image flipped 45 degrees will look weird drawn on the screen so you probably have to scale it up so it fits the screen but still be rotated. That you left out, an image rotated 180 degrees or 90 degrees should work better.

Comment: I am drawing to the screen with spriteBatch. I have done what you have said. The image looks right when it is upside down and the right way up but increases to much in size when it is rotated between. Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: ScaleX ends up being equal to infinity now.

Comment: I added a solution that for me gives me the new width and height after a rotation. I hope you can use that. However, any image rotated 45 degrees will look weird while trying to fit it out an area that isn't also rotated 45 degrees so you have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a RotateTransform to transform the image, then enclose that in a LayoutTransform to fill the dimensions of the container (the screen in this case).

Comment: can you give some example code explaining how to do this in xna